# How to initialize object from a different class and maintain state

Tags: java, oop, variables, static

I'm quite new on Java and I need some help please.

The thing is I have a main class with a null variable object on it (required to be null at start) and a menu with different options to change this variable status.

Each option is controlled by a different class which changes the status of this variable.

How could I initialize this variable from the #1 option class and maintain the status of this variable through options without declaring this variable static?

Executing menu option #2 requires variable to be initialized.

The menu is not on the same "main" class because I'm trying to make it reusable using heritage and polymorphism for it.

```
Class Problem { //main class
    private Control control;
}

Class Option1{
    //initialize the variable control = new Control();
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pass the class in a constructor, create a setter in the original class?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

> The menu is not on the same "main" class because i'm traying to make it reusable using heritage and polimorfism for it.

Please keep in mind that inheritance is not a good way to "reuse code".
Inheritance must qualify for an *is a* relationship. Reuse of code is better accomplished by *composition*.

Comment: I made a menu with an arraylist of options(objects). Each option has a name and executes a function. Option is a superclass and each class extends from it. So you can code each option separately, then with polimorfism, you can "inject" each option into the menu as a seperate module so you can add the number of options you want.The idea is not mine of course, but i think, on my humble opinion, is quite good. But i'm a begginer atm. Do not get it wrong, I sincerely apreciate your answer. In fact, isn't it composition?

Comment: @PabloHernandez Here is another idea for you: walk through the Tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I could give is to make it part of the constructor in the other classes (every class except the one where you initialize it to null) and pass it every time you use the "menu"